# Spring Boot Server not loading React webpage

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, maven, webpack

## Issue:

Hello! I've been spending a fair bit of time now trying to get a Spring Boot server to host a React Application. I've been able to work out nearly everything except for this last issue and that's getting the React Page to render.

The page (called "Library") is opened by the server. I know this part of the server is working correctly for two reasons.

1. The browser tab's name is set to "Library" like it should.
2. When I set the page to only open an HTML page with a simple h1 header that says "Hello", it works as well.

[image]
[image]

## Thoughts:

<s>The issue seems to be coming from **Thymeleaf** but I can't find the cause of the problem.</s>  The issue doesn't seem to be Thymeleaf after-all but another issue in the configuration. Though I may be incorrect about this. I've tried a variety of settings and configurations and the one I have now seems to be working the best overall.

It doesn't seem that the React application is the cause. I am building the react project with no obvious issues occurring during the build process. All files are being generated where they're expected. When I open the resulting Webpack bundle as a standalone file in a browser, it opens and functions like it should.

The server itself is, this issue notwithstanding, running exactly as expected.

There is no REST functionality currently being used. The only goal of this server, as of right now, is to simply open the React application.

## Files/Configuration:

These are all of the files that I think are relevant. I'll add more if they're requested.

### File Structure

```
+-- src
   +-- \main
      +-- \java
      +-- \react
      +-- \resources
         +-- \templates
            +-- bundle.js
            +-- index.html
            +-- bundle.js.License.txt
         +-- application.properties
   +-- \test
+-- package.json
+-- pom.xml
+-- webpack.config.js
```

### Webpack.Config.js

```
var path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main/react/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/main/resources/templates/"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            }
            
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/main/react/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "acorn": "^8.7.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-tabulator": "^0.16.1",
    "rest": "^1.3.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm start",
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch -d --output ./target/classes/static/built/bundle.js"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.16",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.7",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.35.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/>  <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>jweber.code</groupId>
    <artifactId>Library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Library</name>
    <description>Library Website</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### aplication.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false  
spring.thymeleaf.suffix: .html
```

## Closing:

I'll keep looking for a solution in the meantime and I'll be sure to update the post with any findings that I come across. Thanks for any help!

## Followup:

**4/24 8:22 am EST**

I've added a "mode" field to **webpack.config.js** and that removed a warning from the react build process but not much more. I've also reworked the dependencies in the **pom.xml** file to see if there was an issue arising from the order or from an unneeded one. I did run a clean install but this did nothing either. I've updated the files shown above with the new information.

Comment: I'm new with React, have only used it in tutorials where it is a client for spring microservices. The React-based page in these tutorials always runs via its own server, e.g., requiring "nmp start" command. Does Spring Boot w/Thymeleaf need to do anything extra for the React code to run? (Am looking forward to learning about this.) Perhaps your "Library" header displayed because it is simple, well-formed html and the other react-based parts of the page threw errors and were ignored? Have you checked the page using <F12> developer tool?

Comment: I did a search on "react thymeleaf" and the lack of results has me wondering if the two are even very compatible. There would be more tutorials combining the two if they were, I would think.

Comment: React by itself is just a Javascript library that sits in your browser after loading a HTML page that instructed it to load that javascript code. After bundling it via i.e. Webpack you should have a js file somewhere which you can load as any other typical JS file/library within your page. Therefore what you are looking for is probably something along the lines of [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-css-js)

Comment: @PhilFreihofner You are correct, the react application can be run on its own server. Typically on port 3000. Thymeleaf's main goal, and I'm quoting from the Thymeleaf site, _"to bring elegant natural templates to your development workflow — HTML that can be correctly displayed in browsers and also work as static prototypes, allowing for stronger collaboration in development teams."_ I was given to understand that this meant that Thymeleaf was used to act as a sort of hypervisor that allows a React application to work when not hosted directly from NPM. I was mistaken.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner The more and more I researched this problem. The more and more I agree with you. I've dropped Thymeleaf as well as WebPack from my project. More details in the answer.

Comment: @RomanVottner React "sitting" in the server was the core detail that I missed. The process of bundling was working correctly, I did have a **bundle.js** file after Webpack was finished running and when I clicked on its associated **index.html** file, the react application would open in a browser exactly like I expected. <br/>I've dropped Thymeleaf for the time being along with Webpack and automated the process myself and now things work as I expect them too. I'll have more details in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after a week of thinking this problem over, (I stopped for a time because of intense frustration) I've worked out a way that I feel to be much better.

Part of the solution was to drop both Thymeleaf and Webpack. The other was an extensive restructure of the project.

I've broken the larger project up into two separate domains. One for the Frontend and the other for the Backend.

## File Structure:

```
+-- Website
    +-- \Backend
        +-- \src
            +-- \main
                +-- \java
                +-- \resources
            +-- \test
        +-- \target
            +-- \classes
                +-- \static
        +-- pom.xml
    +-- \Frontend
        +-- \build
        +-- \public
        +-- \src
        +-- package.json
        +-- build.bat
        +-- build_script.ps1
```

A standard **npm run build** command will create all the files needed to host a react application on a Spring Boot server. Webpack is not a requirement and by extension, neither is Thymeleaf. All that's required is to then copy/paste the resulting files from the **\Frontend\build** folder into the **\Backend\target\classes\static** folder. I created a Powershell file called **build_script.ps1** that runs the build script for the react application and then copys the newly built files into the intended folder on the backend. The **build.bat** file simply runs the Powershell file without me needing to type a lot into command prompt.

## build_script.ps1:

```
#Variables
$Directory = "{dir}\LibraryWebsite\Frontend"
$sourceDirectory = "{dir}\LibraryWebsite\Frontend\build\*"
$targetDirectory = "{dir}\LibraryWebsite\Backend\target\classes\static"

#test

#Build the application and then copy it to the server's 
cd $Directory
npm run-script build
Copy-Item -Force -Recurse $sourceDirectory -Destination $targetDirectory
```

All of this results in a much cleaner program structure and no meaningful increase in my workload. Everything is done with ./build.

I may return to Thymeleaf at some point in the future (If I hate myself) but this meets my needs for the time being.